# Android does SafetyNet API quota apply to secondary methods?

Tags: android, safetynet

according to the Google docs for the SafetyNet API [here](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/attestation.html) there is a quota attest() method.

From the documentation for the SafetyNetApi [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/safetynet/SafetyNetApi) I see there are other methods, such as:
isVerifyAppsEnabled(), listHarmfulApps(), lookupUri()

Do you know if those methods count against the quota as well?
I didn't see any mention of quota or limit on the doc pages.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Verify Apps is an offline API, so it doesn't need an API key, or have any quotas. As you can see, `isVerifyAppsEnabled` and `listHarmfulApps` don't have any way to set a key.

Safe Browsing *does* indeed need an API key, and does have quotas. While the default quota is not publicly documented, it should be enough for most casual users.

If you have a popular app, and you do reach your quota, then it is very likely that you already have a contact at Google. In this case, you should contact them to discuss the possibility of any quota increases.